# Storyboard for multiple frames

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I would like to animate the opacity of three frames and the timeline for their opacity value should look like in the image. Also the animation should be forever but I also want a delay between each cycle. I mean the opacity should hold onto the last value of '1' for some specified time and then the timeline should repeat again. I tried using a storyboard with three double animations but I cannot figure out the delay between each cycle and the delay between each animation. Setting begin time for each animation did not work for me.

[image: Timeline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the flexibility of Animation in WPF, there are many ways to solve this. Here I introduce the most intuitive solution. From your image, you have to use some kind of discrete KeyFrame. In this case we need 3 `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`, each one should have 2 `DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame`. All these keyframes should be the same. We just need to set the `BeginTime` of `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` appropriately. We don't need to set the `Duration`, it will be deferred automatically based on the `KeyTime` (of `DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame`) combined with the `BeginTime` (of `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`).
However we have to set the `Duration` for the last `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` if you want some delay between the cycles.

Here is a simple example:

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"  
                          RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="i1"
                                                BeginTime="0:0:0">
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
                 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="i2" 
                                                BeginTime="0:0:1">
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
                 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="i3" 
                                            BeginTime="0:0:2" Duration="0:0:3">
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
                 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
       </EventTrigger>
   </StackPanel.Triggers>
   <TextBlock Name="i1">Item 1</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock Name="i2">Item 2</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock Name="i3">Item 3</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

I used `TextBlock` in this code for simplicity. Here you can see that the time of being in `0` opacity (for each `TextBlock`) is 1 second. From that you can derive the `BeginTime` correctly for each `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`. The last one has `Duration` of `3` seconds, that means the delay is about `2` seconds (1 second of the last animation is deducted from the total 3).

Comment: Hi King, thanks for your reply and it works great!! However, I have one issue with it ... my frames disappear after the animation takes place. That is, between every cycle, all 3 disappear once before the whole thing starts again. However, if I copy paste your solution, it works fine! I am doing it in the code behind but I guess I used the same logic. Any idea?

Comment: @schwarz do you mean your code behind which does the same logic does not work expectedly? Well if so it's hard to say what's wrong. You should double check it.

Comment: @schwarz I think the problem is the `BeginTime` which is too soon, I mean it starts even when the duration of `0` opacity has not been passed. In your code, that duration is still `1` second (like in my code) but the `BeginTime` for the second animation is `0.1` (while it should be `1`) and the third is `0.2` (while it should be `2`).

Comment: Ýeah you are right! I know what you mean ... issue solved, thanx again!!